# How to reset buttons when using touchesBegan

Tags: ios, sprite-kit

When I use touchesBegan on my sprite kit game the buttons press down fine the first time but are unresponsive the second time, how do I "reset" these buttons if you will. Buttons are as follows:

```
- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];
    CGPoint location = [touch locationInNode:self];
    SKNode *node = [self nodeAtPoint:location];


    if ([node.name isEqualToString:@"Button"]) {

        [self runAction:[SKAction playSoundFileNamed:@"sound" waitForCompletion: NO]];
             GKGameCenterViewController *gameCenterController = [[GKGameCenterViewController       
 alloc]
                                                        init];
        if (gameCenterController != nil)
        {
            gameCenterController.gameCenterDelegate = self;
            gameCenterController.viewState = GKGameCenterViewControllerStateAchievements;
            UIViewController *vc = self.view.window.rootViewController;
           [vc presentViewController: gameCenterController animated: YES completion:nil];
                    }

    }
```

Thanks for your help!

Comment: That code works fine in my SpriteKit test project.  I think the problem must be in the .... part.

Comment: the problem doesn't actually occur there (I should have been clearer), if the player clicks a button that goes to game center for example but they haven't logged in, it comes up with the standard message, but then they can't click any of the other buttons

Comment: I would put an `NSLog(@"%@",node);` ahead of the `if` statement. That will prove that `touchesBegan` is still working and will show the name of the node that was clicked.

Comment: That shows the names of all the buttons, but i still have the problem

Comment: Interestingly after you touch a button once, in addition to not being able to touch the other buttons you also can't touch the iAds at the top of the screen

Comment: You are not providing enough information to answer your question.

Comment: ok I added more to the question but other than that i don't think there is really any more significant information

Comment: Perhaps if you post code related to the initialisation of said buttons, we might be able to help.